# Barcode scanner on Com port can be opened by putty but not on c#

Tags: c#, windows, serial-port, barcode-scanner

I have a barcode scanner `Tysso GS-6000` connected over a COM port to my computer. The device is called `STMicroelectronics Virtual COM Port (Com30)`.

If I open COM port 30 in Putty and scan some barcodes, I get the correct barcode in the terminal, but when I try to open it with a C# program I cannot open it and instead get an exception:

```
A Device connected to the system doesn't work.
```

My code:

```
try {
  unsafe {
    string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
    serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
    serialPort1.RtsEnable = true;
    serialPort1.PortName = "COM30";
    serialPort1.Open();
    logbox.Text += "OK : Barcode Comport open." + Environment.NewLine;
  }
} catch (Exception ef) {
  MessageBox.Show("Fout bij openen barcode comport : " + ef.Message.ToString());
}
```

The `unsafe` can be ignored since I've tried both `safe` and `unsafe` with 
the same result.

In "Devices & Printers" the device is under the "Unknown" group, but there is no yellow mark on the device. Windows says the device is working correctly.

So why can Putty open and read the COM port but the C# application can not?

Comment: Tysso (is the correct name of the barcode scanner ;)

Comment: Windows does require `\\.\` for the C API(not sure if it's still needed for C#); [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677127/accessing-com10-or-greater-port-in-c-sharp) another question that may help.